# How to apply Git clean filter on working tree file?

Tags: git, filter

I want to let Git run all configured filters on my working tree file and print the resulting output (i.e. the same content which would be written to the Index). Is there a Git command to do that? For example, I'm looking for something like:

```
$ git the-command-i-am-looking-for < huge-lfs-file
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:60ab6bad73e833318d3ad4a186c7ea77e0cf26c1419474dd6786db1c53a366c6
size 1050624
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Git command to do it.

To do it manually, you would have to identify which filter is to be applied to the file, and then run that filter.  If the filter is an old style driver, running it is pretty easy.  If it's a new style driver, running it is more difficult.  Finding it is potentially a bit tricky, but in practice easy.

Everything is documented in [the gitattributes manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html).  The filter to be applied is the one specified by the "best matching" `filter=name`.  The "best match" is the last one taken, and matches are applied in order, starting from the top level `.gitattributes` file and working down the work-tree to the nearest `.gitattributes` file in whatever subdirectory a file lives in.  For instance, if the project itself has:

```
.gitattributes
dir/.gitattributes
dir/sub/.gitattributes
dir/sub/subsub/.gitattributes
```

and the file itself is named `dir/sub/name.ext`, we look in `.gitattributes` for any pattern matching `name.ext` and take its definitions:

```
$ cat .gitattributes
* driver=d1
*.ext driver=d2
name.* driver=d3
```

Since `name.ext` matches `*`, the first line applies.  Since `name.ext` matches `*.ext`, the second line also applies.  Since `name.ext` matches `name.*`, the third line also applies, so the best match *so far* is `d3`.

Then we look in `dir/.gitattributes`:

```
$ cat dir/.gitattributes
*.ext driver=d4
*.dat driver=d5
```

This `*.ext` also matches, so the best match so far is now `d4`.

Now we look in `dir/sub/.gitattributes`:

```
$ cat dir/sub/.gitattributes
* driver=d6
```

This `*` matches, so the best match so far is `d6`.

There is a `dir/sub/subsub/.gitattributes`, but we don't look there because the file is in `dir/sub`, not `dir/sub/subsub`.  So the driver to apply to `dir/sub/name.ext` is `d6`.

Now we merely have to locate the actual driver for `d6`, which we do by running `git config --get`:

```
git config --get filter.d6.clean
```

Whatever comes out of this is the clean filter we should apply to `dir/sub/name.ext`.  (Let's say that's either `run-d6 %f` or just `run-d6`.)  Now, however, we must check whether there is a `filter.d6.process` setting:

```
git config --get filter.d6.process
```

If there is *no* such setting (which `git config` indicates by exiting with a nonzero status), we have an old style driver filter, which is easy to run: it just reads its standard input and writes its standard output, and perhaps takes the file's path name as an argument.  If the invocation line was `run-d6 %f` we just run:

```
git clean dir/sub/name.ext < dir/sub/name.ext > /tmp/cleaned
```

for instance.

If there *is* a `filter.d6.process`, though, invoking it to clean `dir/sub/name.ext` is considerably trickier.  See the documentation for details.  Unfortunately, modern Git-LFS uses long running filter processes (in fact I believe Git-LFS is the *reason* these exist at all), but I suspect there is some backwards compatibility method to invoke it one file at a time since long-running filter processes are still relatively new.

(Note that in practice, people don't build complicated `.gitattributes` tree structures.  For Git-LFS in particular there's just one `.gitattributes` at the top level that runs *everything* through the long-running process.)